# Add custom attribute without quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to add an attribute to a HTML tag without quotes, so I can add a slash before the quotes and add the quotes manually.

The src attribute needs to stay empty, I can't rename it.

My current code looks like this.

```
data = open('data.sql')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for img in soup.find_all(name="img"):

    #get src
    src = img['src']

    # clear src
    img['src'] = ""

    # add new attribute
    img.attrs["data-src"] = src
    print(img.attrs["data-src"])


#save soup
with open('db.sql', "w") as file:
    file.write(str(soup))
```

My result (after saving it to db.sql):

```
<img src="" data-src='\"/folder/img/image.jpg\"'>
```

What I'm looking for (without single quotes):

```
<img src=\"/folder/img/image.jpg\">
```

**What I'm trying is:** 
Load in db.sql with Bs4 
Set src-data attribute to src value 
Clear value of src attribute 
Save file to db2.sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem was to loop trough the database rows, get the column with the HTML inside and create a soup (Bs4) of that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `del` to remove attributes:

```py
for img in soup.find_all(name="img"):
    src = img['src']
    del img['src']
    img.attrs['data-src'] = src
```

Comment: I'm not looking to delete the src attribute. The problem is the single quotes around the new value, I don't want them.

Comment: @JeroenR Ah I misread your desired output. However, there are no single quotes around the resulting tag. They are only displayed in your Python console because that’s how strings are displayed; compare `"hello"` vs `print("hello")`.

Comment: I'm loading in a .sql file, read / modify the html with bs4 and rewrite it to a new .sql file. When that happens I get single quotes around my values (inside the sql file)

Comment: @JeroenR If that’s the case then that’s due to how you write the SQL code, not due to your manipulation of the HTML document. In other words, it’s unrelated, and you will have the same issue with the original, unmodified document.

Comment: @JeroenR If that’s indeed your actual code and output, then this means that the nested quotes were already part of the source HTML code. … I’m also a bit puzzled why you’re the `.sql` file extension for HTML files.

Comment: There is html code inside my database that I wan't to change. So I thought: create a sql dump, read the .sql file with python, change the html (img tags) and save it again and import the modified database. But you are right that it's a converting problem from bs4.